# Custom PHP URL to Controller mapping similar to Symfony2

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, symfony, mapping

I wanna make a simple URL to Controller mapping very much like what Symfony2 does. But that's all I want from Symfony2, rest of it is just too much for me.

For those who don't know what Symfony2 does:

```
blog_home:
    pattern:   /blog
    defaults:  { _controller: BlogBundle:Blog:index }

blog_show:
    pattern:   /blog/{slug}
    defaults:  { _controller: BlogBundle:Blog:show }
```

in a YAML config file.

YAML doesn't matter to me at all. I just wanna achieve the same functionality. To be able to map custom URLs to controller functions.

Maybe an open source mapping class or routing framework? Maybe some tutorials? Ideas to make my own? Any suggestions would be helpful.

I should mention I'm no PHP whiz, I know just enough or maybe a little less than enough. Which is why I don't wanna get into a full featured framework.

Comment: a) If you want to do it like symfony, why you dont use symfony? b) If you want to do it like symfony, why you don't look into the source of symfony?

Comment: Because with Symfony2 comes Doctrine2 which has DQL, Entity, Fixtures and other words I've never heard. Things that make it so complex that my app would never see that cloud. I wanna do routing Symfony way because it made sense to me, unfortunately rest of Symfony didn't. If you have a better option for routing, I am very open to suggestions. About Symfony source I did check out their routing component (https://github.com/symfony/Routing) but their is no information on how to use it and the source: well let's just say I'm looking into it and it's gonna be a while.

Comment: As far as I can see you are not forced to use the things, you don't want to use.

Comment: I read the docs. Entities and DQL are kinda the base of the whole database system, and I just couldn't figure out it's security system. It was a bit much for me. I'm still not giving up on learning it. But for now I have to get work done and if I choose Symfony2 then I will never finish in time.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I appreciate you taking out the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my url routing framework:

```
function route($url, $map) {
    foreach($map as $re => $fn) {
        if(preg_match("~^$re$~", $url, $args)) {
            list($class, $method) = explode(".", $fn);
            return call_user_func_array(
                array(new $class, $method),
                array_slice($args, 1));
        }
    }
    error_404();
}
```

The $map is an array whose keys are regular expressions to match the url against and the values are strings "ClassName.method", like

```
$map = array(
    "/blog/(.+)"          => "BlogController.show",
    "/blog"               => "BlogController.blog",
    "/foobar/(\d+)/(\w+)" => "Foobar.stuff",
);
```

The routing function finds the first matching pattern, instantiates a class and calls a method passing regexp subgroups as arguments. So, an url "/foobar/123/hello" will be routed to `Foobar->stuff(123, 'hello')`.

Comment: Oh this is it. This is perfect. Just what I wanted. Thank you so much. Very cool. Thanks a lot.